# autocomplete search how to show different areas of city but my code showing outside of specific city why

Tags: google-maps

I am searching  for Kuala Lampur, Malaysia. But when I search, it shows me areas outside of Kuala Lampur. Please help me. I am using the Google maps API with `Javascript`.
I have tried lots of things, but I can't find a specific answer. 
I am getting southwest `latlng` and northeast `latlng` from database and showing bounds check.

```
var cityBounds = {
      north: 33.6629104
      south: 33.469683
      east: 72.91419970000001
      west: 73.15187969999999
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 3.139003, lng: 101.686855}
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
var options = {
    bounds:cityBounds,
    types: ['establishment'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'MY'}
};      
var input = (document.getElementById('searchTextField'));
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.27 of Maps JavaScript API, which is currently (January 2017) the experimental version, introduces a new field in google.maps.places.AutocompleteOptions object specification:

> **strictBounds** A boolean value, indicating that the Autocomplete widget should only return those places that are inside the bounds of the Autocomplete widget at the time the query is sent. Setting strictBounds to false (which is the default) will make the results biased towards, but not restricted to, places contained within the bounds.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions

You can load version 3.27 and extend your options like

```
var options = {
    bounds:cityBounds,
    types: ['establishment'],
    strictBounds: true,
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'MY'}
};
```

Comment: thanks bro but still facing problem i am getting sw ne bounds from database check this
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    <?php
        $total_lat_lon = count($locations);
          $cont = 1;
             foreach($locations as $loc)
       {
?>
       new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $loc['sw_lat']; ?>, <?php echo $loc['sw_lng']; ?>),new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $loc['ne_lat']; ?>, <?php echo $loc['ne_lng']; ?>)<?php if($cont <$total_lat_lon){?>, <?php } ?>
<?php $cont++; } ?>
      );

Comment: please help me.
how we can get bounds of three cities and restrict autocomplete search for these specific cities